# Shrink the content div if floated sidebar exists to keep side-by-side

Tags: css, css-float

I have a 'container' that has either one or two div's in it: think 'content area' with optional 'sidebar'.

The sidebar is on the right, the content area on the left.  When the sidebar appears it is a fixed width.

How can I shrink the content container to keep the columns side-by-side without using JavaScript, and without putting additional tags or styles in the html on the fly?

Here's the basic code:

```
<div id='container'>
   <div id='content-area'> ... </div>
   <div id='sidebar' style='width: 200px;'> ...</div>
</div>
```

I tried simply floating one to the left, the other to the right, but in that case the content still retains full-width, and is laid out once clear of the sidebar.

If I knew which pages the sidebar was going to appear on I could give the container a class (on those pages only) and give the class a fixed width.  But I don't know which pages the sidebar will appear on!

Comment: can you please specify ur css..!

Comment: write .container-area{ float:left;} .sidebar{float:right} in css

Comment: Having trouble figuring out your issue.  They seem to float well: http://jsfiddle.net/BBxpg/

Comment: Ya, will have to see the remaining parts of your CSS because just with float it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/zEntc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using CSS [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `#sidebar + #content-area` you could target the content area and apply a right margin to it if only the sidebar exists within the container:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/upuqom/1/edit)**

```css
#sidebar { float: right; width: 200px; }

#sidebar + #content-area {
  margin-right: 200px; /* equal to the width of the sidebar */
}
```

> **[5.7 Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)**
>
> Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: `E1 + E2`, where
>   `E2` is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if `E1` and
>   `E2` share the same parent in the document tree and `E1` immediately
>   precedes `E2`, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and
>   comments).

In this case you have to reorder the elements as follows:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar"> This is the sidebar </div>
    <div id="content-area"> This is the content. </div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could prevent the content area from [overlapping the margin box of the floated sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475822/why-does-css-float-not-change-the-width-of-the-following-div/25476238#25476238) by establishing a [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting).

CSS level 2 spec [sates](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats):

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an
>   element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting
>   context (such as an element with *'overflow' other than 'visible'*) must
>   not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting
>   context as the element itself.

Therefore by giving the content area an [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) property with a value of `hidden` (for instance), it would shrink to the left side of the sidebar which is floated to the right.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/upuqom/2/edit)**

```css
#content-area { overflow-x: hidden; }
#sidebar { float: right; width: 200px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple css, that works well for all your pages, both with siebar and without sidebar

HTML: Sidebar first, then content-area (no matter the sidebar should be on left or right)

```
<div id='container'>
   <div id='sidebar' style='width: 200px;'> ...</div>
   <div id='content-area'> ... </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content-area{
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
#sidebar{
   float:right;
}
```

Give `float: left` for #sidebar if you want it to be on left

Note:

- If you include sidebar in a page, it will take 200px width and the content-area will take up the rest of the width.
- In you pages that dont include the sidebar, the content-area will take up full width.

Hope thats what you are looking for.